# Call link function directive Angular 1 ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ecmascript-6

I create a directive based on ES6 style:

```
export default class myDirective {
   constructor() {
       this.restrict = 'E';
       this.scope = {};

       this.link = link;
   }
   link() {
       console.log('link myDirective');
   }
}
```

then in `index.js`:

```
import angular from 'angular';

import myDirective from './myDirective';

export default angular
                .module('app.directives', [])
                .directive('myDirective ', () => new myDirective())
                .name;
```

But when I call myDirective on html like: `<my-directive><my-directive>` it does not call link function or compile function. What can I do?

Comment: Can you try removing this.link = link; from constructor.

Comment: I tried but does not work :/

Comment: umm, it's working fine for me. The only problem is that your directive has a space char on it's name which breaks the declaration (`'myDirective '`, remove the space), dispite that, it worked for me.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro you see log from link function? My directive works fine but I can not see log from link function.

Comment: Yes, it has logged just fine. Have you faced any console errors ? Can you log the `myDirective` instance and see if it's defined?

Comment: `function () {return new _datatables2.default();
 }`

Comment: Well, it's weird, doesn't seem like your class.

Comment: Yeah! It's seems weird.

Comment: I've reproduced your code on a fiddle and the only thing changed is the removed space that I've told before. Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/p431f33p/

Comment: Yeah @LenilsondeCastro. But here it does not work :( I'm using webpack and es6

Answer (score 0):

We use ES6 here, and our directives dont really look like that, I'll give an example:

```
import templateUrl from './some.html';
import SomeController from './someController';
export default () => ({
  templateUrl,
  controller: SomeController,
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  scope: {
    someVariable: '='
  },
  link: (scope, element, attrs, controller) => {
    scope.link = {
      someFunction: function some() { }
    }
  },
  bindToController: true
});
```

You get the idea anyway. Try structuring it like that and see if the link function works as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using AngularJS + ES6 + Webpack. Maybe you could add this in your Directive, in your compile function:

```
compile() {
    //console.log("compile");  
    return this.link.bind(this);
}
```

Check this links for more acurated info:

https://github.com/geniuscarrier/webpack-angular-es6/blob/master/app/modules/home/directive/footer.js

https://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/exploring-es6-classes-in-angularjs-1.x/